# how to use like and substring in where clause in sql

Tags: string, t-sql, substring, where-clause, sql-like

Hope one can help me and explain this query for me,
why the first query return result but the second does not:

EDIT:
first query:

```
select name from Items where name like '%abc%'
```

second Query:

```
 select name from Items where name like substring('''%abc%''',1,10)
```

why the first return result but the second return nothing while

```
substring('''%abc%''',1,10)='%abc%'
```

If there are a logic behind that, Is there another approach to do something like the second query,

my porpuse is to transform a string like '''abc''' to 'abc' in order to use like statement,

Comment: The two queries have nothing in common. The first one returns part of a string and is essentially a no-op as the string is *less* than 10 characters long. The second just doesn't make any sense - if you wanted to find strings that contain `abc` write `LIKE '%abc%'`. Right now, it seems that you are asking for strings that start and end with `'` and contain `abc` in them?

Comment: Please explain what you actually want to do. BTW `substring` returns part of a string, it doesn't replace anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thax for your answer, I know that they have nothing in common, I am gonna to update that now

Comment: Better explain what you actually want to do and why you can't just write `LIKE '%abc%'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is that clear now?

Comment: It still doesn't seem clear to me, can you provide a specific example of what the input would look like and the desired result?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock thanks for your answer, I will update it again, i need my query get corrected as with simple select it now works, again thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can concatenate strings to form your `LIKE` string. To trim the first 3 and last 3 characters from a string use the `SUBSTRING` and `LEN` functions. The following example assumes your match string is called `@input` and starts and ends with 3 quote marks that need to be removed to find a match:

```
select name from Items where name like '%' + SUBSTRING(@input, 3, LEN(@input) - 4) + '%'
```

Comment: I will test this approach and come back

Comment: this is almost what thing I am looking for when I run this select , but when I used it for example like this : exec sp_executesql N'   select name from Items where name like ''%'' + SUBSTRING(@input, 3, LEN(@input) - 3) + ''%''' does not run

Comment: It also works I have to upload my query, becaz it contains some subqueries and so give the error Incorrect syntax near AS, please reread this question tomorrow